# Wrap php variable in quotes before echoing

Tags: php, html, laravel

I need to use a php variable to echo the id into an input field:

```
<input type="text" id={{ strtolower($val) . "Field" }}/>
```

But with the code above the output is

```
<input type="text" id=waterField/>
```

I want the output to wrapped in double quotes like:

```
<input type="text" id="waterField" />
```

I am using laravel but am totally willing to accomplish it without. 
Is there a simple way to accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pure php, considering you have short tags enabled.

```
<input type="text" id="<? echo strtolower($val) ?>Field" />
```

Answer (score 2):

use

`echo '<input type="text" id="'.strtolower(htmlspecialchars($val)). 'Field"/>';`

OR idle way to use html and php is

`<input type="text" id="<?php echo strtolower(htmlspecialchars($val)); ?>Field"/>`

If `$val` can have quotes in it, then need to clear them by using `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
<input type="text" id="{{ strtolower($val) }}Field"/>
```

Comment: Not sure where `$val` is coming from, but, as pointed out, if there is any doubt that the value in `$val` may contain quotes or other invalid data, then instead use `{{ strtolower(htmlspecialchars($val)) }}`.  For example if `$val` comes from user input. If it's set in code, it's probably not needed though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the double quotes into your html text. Escape the double quotes like this \" so php won't parse them and you're fine.